# Atribuir valor retornado no success a uma variável

Tags: ajax

Tenho a seguinte requisição `ajax` onde retorna o valor no `success`:

```
function novasMensagens(Alerta) {

    var retorno = Alerta > 0 ? Alerta : "";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : './fetchbusca',
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var Alerta = data;
            console.log(Alerta);
        }
    });
}
```

Retorno: `{"0":"1","Alerta":"1"}`

Agora o valor que retorna é `{"Alerta":"1"}` tenho de o atribuir ao Alerta que está dentro da variável retorno:

```
var retorno = Alerta > 0 ? Alerta : "";
```

Comment: @Sam O que pretendo é pegar nessa valor retornado dentro do `sucess` e utilizá-lo noutra função, como o posso fazer?

Comment: @Sam entendi, mas fiz isso e recebo o erro `Alerta is not defined`. Função `function novasMensagens(Alerta){ $.ajax({ type: 'GET', url : './fetchbusca', success : function(data) { var Alerta = data; var retorno = Alerta > 0 ? Alerta : ""; return retorno; } }); } document.getElementById("msgNumero").innerHTML = novasMensagens(Alerta );`

Comment: Quando vc executa `document.getElementById("msgNumero").innerHTML = novasMensagens(Alerta );` o Ajax ainda não foi processado. O Ajax é assíncrono.

Comment: @Sam significa que tenho de colocar o JavaScript dentro do `header`?

Comment: Não. Tudo que vier do Ajax vc deve fazer dentro da função do success. É lá que os valores são retornados.

Answer (score 0):

Da forma que foi escrita a resposta, antes de sofrer qualquer alteração, basta realizar da seguinte maneira:

```
function novasMensagens(Alerta){
  var retorno = Alerta > 0 ? Alerta : "";

  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url : './fetchbusca',
      success : function(data) {
          retorno = data.Alerta
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: faço `conole.log(Alerta);` antes do `ajax` e retorna indefinido, e devia retornar 1

Comment: `Alerta` antes da requisição é o `Alerta` definido como parâmetro do método, então ele terá o valor de antes da requisição, no `success` ficar de acordo com o escopo da variável. Recomendo usar nomes diferentes para poder entender melhor o ocorrido.

Comment: Perceba que `Alerta` não está dentro de retorno, você apenas fez uma checagem nele e atribuiu o valor, não a referência de `Alerta`, pois aparentemente `Alerta` é um inteiro e não um objeto. Para utilizar o valor do retorno do ajax faça sua lógica dentro do success.

Answer (score 0):

O que você está tentando fazer não vai dar certo, pois não tem como recuperar o valor de "Alerta" fora do ajax. Utilize o array "Error" do ajax

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url : './fetchbusca',
          success : function(data) {
              //exibe o alerta
          },
          error:function(){
              //faz algo se der erro
          }

      });
```